# QApplication.setOverrideCursor has no effect on this function, why?

Tags: python, cursor, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm building a relatively simple UI using PyQt5. There are a few points in the application that run a process that takes some time, so I have used QApplication.setOverrideCursor to indicate that a process is running.

This is done through this decorator (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218900/how-can-i-change-the-cursor-shape-with-pyqt)):

```
def waiting_effects(function):
    def new_function(self):
        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor))
        function(self)
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
    return new_function
```

This works for most of the methods in the UI class except for one:

```
@waiting_effects
def load_data_folder(self):

        folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)

        if folder:
            self.clear_plot(name="All")
            self.vr_headers = []
            self.ls_headers = []
            self.df = pvi.import_folder(folder)

            if self.df['voltage recording'] is not None:
                self.vr_headers = self.df['voltage recording'].columns[1:].tolist()
                self.sweeps = self.df['voltage recording'].index.levels[0]

            if self.df['linescan'] is not None:
                self.ls_headers = self.df['linescan'].columns[1::2].tolist()

                if self.df['voltage recording'] is None:
                    self.sweeps = self.df['linescan'].index.levels[0]

                self.ratio_dropdown1.clear()
                self.ratio_dropdown2.clear()
                for profile in self.ls_headers:
                    self.ratio_dropdown1.addItem(profile)
                    self.ratio_dropdown2.addItem(profile)

                self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled(2, True)

            elif self.tabWidget.isTabEnabled(2):
                self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled(2, False)

            self.update_treeWidget()
```

The @waiting_effects decorator in this case does not produce any change in the cursor.

Rather than using the decorator I have tried wrapping the block of code after the QFileDialog with the QApplication.setOverrideCursor, but this has not worked. I.e.:

```
def load_data_folder(self):

        folder = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self)

        QtWidgets.QApplication.setOverrideCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.WaitCursor))
        if folder:
            self.clear_plot(name="All")
            self.vr_headers = []
            self.ls_headers = []
            self.df = pvi.import_folder(folder)

            if self.df['voltage recording'] is not None:
                self.vr_headers = self.df['voltage recording'].columns[1:].tolist()
                self.sweeps = self.df['voltage recording'].index.levels[0]

            if self.df['linescan'] is not None:
                self.ls_headers = self.df['linescan'].columns[1::2].tolist()

                if self.df['voltage recording'] is None:
                    self.sweeps = self.df['linescan'].index.levels[0]

                self.ratio_dropdown1.clear()
                self.ratio_dropdown2.clear()
                for profile in self.ls_headers:
                    self.ratio_dropdown1.addItem(profile)
                    self.ratio_dropdown2.addItem(profile)

                self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled(2, True)

            elif self.tabWidget.isTabEnabled(2):
                self.tabWidget.setTabEnabled(2, False)

            self.update_treeWidget()
        QtWidgets.QApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
```

The slow part of this function is the line:

```
self.df = pvi.import_folder(folder)
```

This import_folder is a function from another module I have written that loads the data folders that our acquisition software generates. I have tried wrapping just this line with QApplication.setOverrideCursor, but again that has not produced any effect.

Any thoughts / suggestions on what might be going on here?

Thanks

Comment: I can't test your code, but try putting `QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()` immediately after the line that sets the cursor.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks!

Feel free to put it in an answer and I'll mark correct

Comment: Also, if you wouldn't mind explaining - what was the issue that that line of code fixes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `load_data_folder` function runs in the main GUI thread, so it will block any further GUI updates until it completes.

Try putting `QtWidgets.qApp.processEvents()` immediately after the line that sets the cursor, and that should allow the cursor to be updated before the function starts.